# Inserting JSON in TSQL

Tags: json, t-sql

I would like to insert JSON into SQL table using TSQL. The JSON itself contains columnnames and row objects

```
{
  "content": {
    "columns": [
      {
        "name": "col1",
        "dataType": "float"
      },
      {
        "name": "col2",
        "dataType": "float"
      }
    ],
    "rows": [
      [
        0,
        2
      ],
      [
        4,
    5
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the expected result. Table can be defined upfront, but order in the JSON may not always be the same

```
col1,col2
0,2
4,5
```

Comment: For your next question please try to add a [mcve]. SO is not a *please-write-my-code* platform... And please always state the RDBMS (product and version). `[tsql]` points to SQL-Server, but this is not sure. Furthermore, SQL-Server 2016+ supports JSON natively, lower versions don't...

Answer (score 1):

If this is SQL-Server 2016+ you can use the native JSON support like this:

```
DECLARE @YourJson NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'{
  "content": {
    "columns": [
      {
        "name": "col1",
        "dataType": "float"
      },
      {
        "name": "col2",
        "dataType": "float"
      }
    ],
    "rows": [
      [
        0,
        2
      ],
      [
        4,
    5
      ]
    ]
  }
}';
```

--Declare or create a target table

```
DECLARE @predefinedTable TABLE(col1 FLOAT, col2 FLOAT);
```

--Read the values from the JSON

```
INSERT INTO @predefinedTable(col1,col2) 
SELECT TheJsonsContent.col1
      ,TheJsonsContent.col2  
FROM OPENJSON(@YourJson,'$.content.rows')
     WITH(col1 FLOAT '$[0]'
         ,col2 FLOAT '$[1]') TheJsonsContent;
```

--Check the result

```
SELECT * FROM @predefinedTable;
```

The idea in short:

We use `OPENJSON` to get the array within `$.content.rows`. Then we use the `WITH`-clause to grab the values by their position (zero-based).

Hint: If you are with another RDBMS or a lower version, this will get tricky... Depending on the JSON's complexity you'll need a lot of parsing... In this case, I'd suggest to use another tool.